# How to create "if condition" based on method names in java

Tags: java

I have 2 methods with names

```
firstMethod()
secondMethod()
```

I wanted to have a if condition based on method names.

For example:

```
if (methodName.contains (firstMethod()))
{

}
else
{

}
```

Is it possible in Java?

Comment: Do you know the method names beforehand?

Comment: yes, i know the method names before itself [for instance- Here firstMethod() and secondMethod() ]

Comment: You want to know if a method **name** contains the **return value** of another method? Why in heaven's name would you want that? Can you give us your real-world use case? Why not just use the string (since you know the method name at the time you're writing the code)?

Comment: Let me guess, you want to create a separate method which does different things if it was called from either `firstMethod` or `secondMethod`. Please don't do that.

Comment: Annotations might be a better way to do what you're doing, depending on whatever it is that you're actually doing

Comment: if @Tom is right then yes, please don't do that. Make it into two separate methods. If there is a lot of common code between the two then you can split those pieces into their own methods.

Comment: do you want to use this in a test to see if the method was called?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Basically reflection is a mechanism to pass from strings to Classes, Methods, Constructors and viceversa.

But is not clear how would you like to use it, so I don't know how to be more clear.

In any case you need to obtain a reference to a [Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html). From the class Method is possible to get the name of that method as a String with the method [getName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getName()).

Once you have strings you can compare them as usually using string methods.

Comment: Thanks All for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely really do not want to do that. Instead why not have an parameter on the method you are calling, and have that dictate what the behaviour is. For example:

```
void firstMethod() {
   someMethod(true);
}

void secondMethod() {
   someMethod(false);
}

void someMethod(boolean fromFirstMethod) {
   if (fromFirstMethod) {
      // some code...
   } else {
      // some other code...
   }
}
```

Comment: Even though that might do what OP wants, it is still ugly. But it is not your fault that OP wants that.

Comment: yeah, agree it's ugly, it was more of an attempt to show OP a simple alternative to the reflection answers, which are beyond overkill for a trivial problem like this. This can easily be refactored into something a bit nicer. If we had more of the OPs code to base our answers on perhaps things like Strategy patterns or basic inheritance might have provided a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

`Class.java` have a method `#getDeclaredMethods` which returns an array containing `Method` objects reflecting all the declared methods of the class. `Method` class, in turn, has `#getName()` which returns a `String` representation of method name.